# Virtual keyboard input to data grid view

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

[image]

i want to input digits from virtual keyboard.

i tried by sendKeys. it not working as expected. it replace digit

```
dataGridViewTransation.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("{4}");
```

how to overcome this ?

Comment: when I use your code snippet on a ´RichTextBox´ it works fine. Could you post more code? are these two lines all that happens when you press one of the number buttons on your gui?

Comment: yes, on two line when i press number key

Comment: I closed the post as duplicate of linked post. Let me know if you have any question about the linked answer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I will after trying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can append text to a DataGridView Cell. I would store the current value in a string, then update that variable before setting the text to the cell.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the currently selected Cell
        string msg = String.Format("Row: {0}, Column: {1}",
        DGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex,
        DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);

        //Update our New Cell Value Data
        newValue = newValue + "4";

        //Apply the New Cell Value Data to the Selected Cell
        this.DGV.CurrentCell.Value = newValue;
    }
```